# C# Polymorphism with Lists

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

Given the following 6 classes.
Why do I get a compiler error when using Polymorphism with lists, but not when using a single object? What have I missed? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Class BaseDevice {}

Class DeviceA : Class BaseDevice {}

Class DeviceB : Class BaseDevice {}


Class BaseDevicesCfg {
  List<BaseDevice> Devices; //either a List of DeviceA obejcts or a list of DeviceB objects
  BaseDevice Device; //single  DeviceA obejct or DeviceB object
}

Class DevicesACfg : BaseDevicesCfg {
   
   Devices = new List<DeviceA>();   --> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.List<DeviceA> to System.Collection.Generic.List<BaseDevice>
   
   Device = new DeviceA();  --> No Error
   
}

Class DevicesBCfg  : BaseDevicesCfg {

   Devices = new List<DeviceB>();  --> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.List<DeviceB> to System.Collection.Generic.List<BaseDevice>
   
   Device = new DeviceB();    --> No Error
}
```

Comment: `Class DeviceA : Class BaseDevice {}` I don't think this is a C# syntax?! Should be `class DeviceA : BaseDevice {}`

Comment: Are you sure this is C#? This kind of syntax actually quite confuses me. For me, it looks more like Visual Basic and C# combined. The `Class` needs to be lowercase to signify a keyword, but it is capitalized.

Comment: Aside from the actual duplicate, please note winscripter's response - this is pseudo-code at the moment. When asking a question, please provide a [mcve] that we can actually try to compile, that would give the errors you're showing (and no other errors). Almost every single line of this code has a problem, mostly unrelated to what you're asking about.

Comment: Simple example, assuming that `Cat` and `Dog` both derive from `Mammal`: You're not allowed to reference a `List<Dog>` via a `List<Mammal>` because otherwise you could add a `Cat` to the `List<Mammal>` which would actually be adding it to the `List<Dog>`. This is the same situation that you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your input and sorry for my bad pseudocode. But I understood my mistake with the explanation from @Mattew Watson